# Expected angular Route.navigate to have been called, but is never called

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm having when spying on injected `Router`. I'm calling a component's method from the unit test. This method in turn calls Router.navigate. When expecting the Router.navigate spy to have been called, I'm getting a failure.

Component

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-comp',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    templateUrl: './comp.component.html',
    styleUrl: './comp.component.scss'
})
export class CompComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public router: Router, public route: ActivatedRoute) {}    

    changeCompNumber(newCompNumber: number) {
        this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { 'comp': newCompNumber }, queryParamsHandling: 'merge'}
    }

}
```

unit test

```js
describe('CompComponent', () => {
    let component: CompComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CompComponent>;
    let ngZone: NgZone;
    let router: Router;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule, CompComponent]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CompComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        ngZone = TestBed.inject(NgZone);
        router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    });

   it("should change comp number", fakeAsync(() => {

        ngZone.run(() => {
            component.changeCompNumber(20);
            tick()
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
        const navSpy = spyOn(router, "navigate");
        expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }))
});
```

Error:

```
Expected spy navigate to have been called.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely spying too late. Try the following:

```
it("should change comp number", fakeAsync(() => {
        // Spy here
        const navSpy = spyOn(router, "navigate");
        ngZone.run(() => {
            component.changeCompNumber(20);
            tick()
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
        expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }))
```

Also, you most likely don't need the `ngZone.run(())`.

```
it("should change comp number", fakeAsync(() => {
        // Spy here
        const navSpy = spyOn(router, "navigate");

        component.changeCompNumber(20);
        tick()
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }))
```

Comment: This worked. I in fact did not need it `NgZone`, also did not need `tick()` or `fakeAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating the spy after executing the function you are testing. This means that there actual function will be invoked instead of the spy.

```
   it("should change comp number", fakeAsync(() => {
    //Arrange
    const navSpy = spyOn(router, "navigate");

    //ACT
    ngZone.run(() => {
        component.changeCompNumber(20);
        tick()
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    //ASSERT
    expect(navSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}))
```

Using the Arrange, Act, Assert pattern can help prevent this from happening.

- Define variables, setting up the scenario, and creating your spies
  (Arrange)
- Execute your function you intend to test (Act)
- Verify your expected outcome (Assert)